# show preview and not all page/forms

Tags: entities, 6

I need to show only the preview and not all page and forms

I made a new window after clicking preview but I see ALL page (a duplicate) including header, footer and form compiled. I need to show the preview only.

```
function node_form_build_preview($form, &$form_state) {
  $node = node_form_submit_build_node($form, $form_state);
  $form_state['node_preview'] = node_preview($node);
}
```

can someone help?

Comment: if someone can help, tell me what you need. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you dont like what Drupal is doing by default for this preview feature, override it in your site theme, there is an example of this in the `node_preview` [Drupal 7 API node_preview() comments](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_preview/7).

**the comment incorrectly titles the function THEME_Node_preview() it should all be lowercase**

```
  /**
   *Output customized node preview on node edit and add forms.
   *
   * @return
   * This just outputs the Full node ignoring the teaser mode.
   */
  function YOURTHEME_node_preview($variables)
  {
      $node = $variables['node'];
      $elements = node_view($node, 'full');
      $full = drupal_render($elements);
      $output = '<div class="preview">';
      $output .= '<h3 class="post-preview" >' . t('Preview of your posting') . '</h3>';
      $output .= $full;
      $output .= "</div>\n";
      return $output;
  }
```

If that still doesn't look right you could try altering this code further to:

- provide an override to node.tpl.php or node--preview.tpl.php using theme suggestions for drupal's theming layer functions.
- alter the results of `$full` above using Regular Expressions to hack off the beginning and end of the HTML page content.

Comment: i'm on drupal 6, it's the same?

Comment: did you look at the drupal 6 API page for that function, a link is at the top of this page: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.pages.inc/function/node_preview/6  ... yes it looks like it would be the same or very similiar. Next time tag your question with "6" for Drupal 6 ...